Make top of the application move when i click on it and move with mouse using C#
I want to make the top of the application move when I click on it and move the mouse. I am using C# and Windows Forms.

By "the application" do you mean a window? All windows are draggable by default, what's causing you to be unable move it? Is it a borderless window? Could you include a screenshot of the window or a [mre] so we could see what's causing your window to not be draggable?

The question is very vague, but I can provide general solution to move control/form along with the cursor (explanations in code):
namespace forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // field to detect when the mouse is down
    private bool _isMouseDown;
    // field to store cursor position when mouse was initially clicked
    private Point _initMousePosition;
    // fields to hold position of the form when mouse was clicked
    private int _initFormX;
    private int _initFormY;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // if we are not in "moving with cursor" mode, we early return
        if (!_isMouseDown) return;
        // here we calculate how much mouse has moved and apply those
        // to create new position for our form.
        var deltaX = _initMousePosition.X - Cursor.Position.X;
        var deltaY = _initMousePosition.Y - Cursor.Position.Y;
        // set new position for form
        Location = new Point(_initFormX - deltaX, _initFormY - deltaY);
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // finish moving together with cursor by setting the flag
        _isMouseDown = false;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // get initial position of form and cursor, set _isMouseDown to true
        _initFormX = Location.X;
        _initFormY = Location.Y;
        _initMousePosition = Cursor.Position;
        _isMouseDown = true;
    }
}

